# Obtener usuarios con un rol determinado con spatie\Permissions Laravel

Tags: laravel-5

Tengo instalado en mi proyecto [laravel 5.8](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/) el paquete [Spatie\Laravel Permissions](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission), en mis mantenedores estoy configurando un módulo donde tengo que listar a todos los usuarios que tienen el rol "Postulantes"...

mi pregunta es la siguiente.

¿Cómo puedo listar a todos los usuarios que tienen el rol "Postulantes"?

he leido la documentacion pero esto solo aparece para 1 solo usuario y lo que necesito es traerme a todos los usuarios que ese rol para poder cargarlos en una lista.

Comment: Muchas Gracias por tu respuesta, esto me dio la solución User::whereHas("roles", function($q){ $q->where("name", "Member"); })->get()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes consultar todos los usuarios que tienen un rol de esta forma

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $usuariosConRol = User::has('roles')->paginate(20);

        return view("home", compact('usuariosConRol'));
    }
}
```

Comment: Buenas, sera que tiene de como traer un rol en especifico de un usuario?

Answer (score 1):

laravel 8.

```
 $usuariosConRol = User::whereHas("roles", function($q){ $q->where("name", "Ventas"); })->get();
```

Esta `query` me funciono para resolver el problema.